# When using GetX observables, which UI widgets need to be wrapped in Obx?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

To learn GetX I created a simple controller class:

```
class MyDataController extends GetxController {
  RxString aString = ''.obs;

  void updateString(String s) {
    aString.value = s;
  }
}
```

`aString`'s value is displayed in two classes: the `AppBar` (not discussed here) and another class in which `aString` is both set and displayed:

```
class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyDataController controller = Get.find();
    final textController = TextEditingController();
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: textController,
          onChanged: (_) {
            controller.updateString(textController.text);
          },
        ),
        Text(controller.aString.value),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I'm confused about which widgets need to be wrapped in an instance of `Obx()`.

If I wrap *only* the `Text()` (display widget) in an `Obx` instance, it's updated when the `TextField()` (input widget) changes. And if I wrap *only* the `TextField()` widget in an `Obx` instance, I get an error message:

> The following message was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty,
> state: _ObxState#019a0):
> [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
> You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
> If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
> or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
> (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
> If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.

Everything seems clear: widgets displaying state must be wrapped in `Obx()` instances to display updated variables. That makes perfect sense. And widgets that change state don't need to be wrapped in `Obx()` instances.

I'm confused, though, because if I wrap *both* widgets in separate `Obx()` instances, I get the error message. But if I wrap the entire `Column()` in an `Obx()` instance, the text is properly updated when the `TextField()` changes. ... What am I missing in my understanding?

Comment: can you specify your question so I can try to explain correctly what you want?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Elmarakby When using GetX,, to change variables' states and then automagically update the UI when values change, which UI widgets should (and should not) be wrapped by Obx() instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it all up to the point when you wrapped the Text widget in an Obx. In actual fact it is best to wrap only the smallest widget that would need updating in Obx, the `Text` widget in this case.

Let me explain what happened the cases in which you tried testing it out:

**Case 1**: When you wrapped only the `Text` widget in Obx (The best thing to do)

This case happen to be the best and most encouraged approach. In this scenario when the value of aString changes in the controller (**MyDataController**) the Obx is notified to re-build **only** the affected `Text` widget from scratch, and this is exactly the aim of GetX.

**Case 2**: When you wrapped both the `Text` && the `TextField` widget in Obx (This will throw an error).

In this case you have wrapped both the `Text` and `TextField` widget in Obx, we can therefore let **case 1** account for the `Text` widget.
Now, moving unto the `TextField` widget, an error will occur because the `TexField` widget is not in any way dependent on any obs-value (observable value).
It is important to note that in the onChanged callback provided to the textField, the method `updateString` called on the `controller` have no effect whatsoever on TextField's parameter and thus this leads GetX to throw an error since you are trying to forcibly update/re-build a widget that needs no rebuilding.

**Case 3**: When you wrapped the whole column in Obx (Will not throw an error but not the best practice).

In this case the widget will be built with no error whatsoever since the `Text` widget (which is inside the Column) is dependent on the value of `aString`. So, let's see what happens when the method **`updateString`** is called.
When the **`updateString`** is called the whole Column is re-built (along with the `TextField` and the `Text` widgets and this action will as well cause the value in the `Text` widget to be updated.
Now, you can see why this third case can be detrimental, if you try wrapping your whole app in Obx, your whole app will then have to get re-built (which can really affect your app's performance negatively. Of course GetX has a way of disallowing that and thus it throws an error when you try wrapping an HeavyWidget in Obx or GetX.

Comment: So I can call GetxController methods and change fields from outside Obx. Widgets are wrapped in Obx only for updating their values, right?

Comment: And it sounds like Case 3, while simple and expedient, presents the same disadvantage as `setState()`, where entire widgets are constantly being rebuilt, more often than really necessary.

Comment: Yeah, something like that.